# Why removing a child element like this doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, dom

There is a problem with the last line inside `txtAgeBlur` function. Why I can't remove the child node like this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Forms</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" name="form1">
    <p>
      Name
      <input type="text" name="txtName">
    </p>
    <p>
      Age
      <input type="text" name="txtAge" size="3" maxlength="3"> 
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="button" value="Check details" name="btnCheckForm">
    </p>
  </form>

  <script>
    var myForm = document.form1;

    function btnCheckFormClick(e) {
      var name = myForm.txtName.value;
      var age = myForm.txtAge.value;

      if (name === "" || age === "") {
        alert("Please complete all of the form");

        if (name === "")
          myForm.txtName.focus();
        else
          myForm.txtAge.focus();
      }
      else
        alert("Thanks for completing the form " + name);
    }

    var messageInserted = false;

    function txtAgeBlur(e) {
      //console.log(e.type);
      var target = e.target;
      var msg = document.createElement("span");
      msg.id = "msg";
      msg.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Please enter a valid age"));

      if (isNaN(target.value)) {
        if (!messageInserted) {
          messageInserted = true;
          target.parentElement.appendChild(msg);
        }
        target.focus();
        target.select();
      }
      else if (messageInserted === true)
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1].removeChild(msg); //problem
    }

    myForm.btnCheckForm.addEventListener("click", btnCheckFormClick);
    myForm.txtAge.addEventListener("blur", txtAgeBlur);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this deletes the child element without any problem. What's the difference between this and the example above?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Forms</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var msg = document.createElement("span");
    msg.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Please enter a valid age"));
    document.body.appendChild(msg);

    var msg2 = document.querySelector("span");
    console.log(msg === msg2);
    document.body.removeChild(msg);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *msg* references the new text node that you created, not the previous one. You might consider `msg.parentNode.removeChild(msg)` in the second case.

Comment: How come they are not the same? In the second example the node assigned to the variable `msg` seems to be the same node I created using `document.body.appendChild(msg);`. The `console.log(msg === msg2);` comparison returns `true`. Why this is not the case in the first example? I am a newbie and I can't really see the difference.

Comment: The function txtAgeBlur gets called every time you leave the age field. This means that the second time you call it, the variable msg is referencing the new textnode as Rob mentioned, rather than the text node in the dom. The reason your second example is working, is because the variable msg still references the node which was inserted into the dom.

Comment: `msg` references a `<span>` not a text node. Other than that, yes, `msg` references a new `<span>` every time `txtAgeBlur` is called. That `<span>` can not be removed because it has never been inserted.

Comment: @Makyen—yes, *msg* is a span not a text node. Doesn't `target.parentElement.appendChild(msg)` insert *mst* given that *target.parentElement* is a P element?

Comment: @RobG, Yes, that inserts `msg`. However, that only happens the first time (i.e. `messageInserted` is `false`)  `txtAgeBlur` is called when `isNaN(target.value)` is `true`. But the removal of `msg` is attempted on subsequent calls to `txtAgeBlur` when `msg` references a different `<span>` that has not been (and never will be) inserted into the DOM.  `var msg = document.createElement("span");` is performed each time `txtAgeBlur` is called, creating a new `<span>`.

Comment: @Makyen—I understand all that, I was referring to "*…can not be removed because it has never been inserted…*".  The *msg* node is inserted the first time, so that one can be removed.

Comment: @RobG, Yes, obviously, the `<span>` that has been inserted can be removed. However, that inserted `<span>` is not what `msg` references when `removeChild(msg)` executes. My statement was in respect to the newly created  `<span>` which `msg` references when `removeChild(msg)` executes. At that point, `msg` references a different `<span>` that has never been inserted and thus can not be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time `txtAgeBlur` is called, you create an new `<span>` which you reference with `msg`.  When you are trying to remove the currently showing message, `msg` references a new `<span>` that has not yet been inserted.  You need to get a reference to the currently showing message to remove it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Forms</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" name="form1">
    <p>
      Name
      <input type="text" name="txtName">
    </p>
    <p>
      Age
      <input type="text" name="txtAge" size="3" maxlength="3"> 
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="button" value="Check details" name="btnCheckForm">
    </p>
  </form>

  <script>
    var myForm = document.form1;

    function btnCheckFormClick(e) {
      var name = myForm.txtName.value;
      var age = myForm.txtAge.value;

      if (name === "" || age === "") {
        alert("Please complete all of the form");

        if (name === "")
          myForm.txtName.focus();
        else
          myForm.txtAge.focus();
      }
      else
        alert("Thanks for completing the form " + name);
    }

    var messageInserted = false;

    function txtAgeBlur(e) {
      //console.log(e.type);
      var target = e.target;
      if (isNaN(target.value)) {
        if (!messageInserted) {
          //There is no reason to do the work of creating the <span> if you are not
          //  going to be inserting it.  Thus, you should create it here, not
          //  every time you call txtAgeBlur.
          var msg = document.createElement("span");
          msg.id = "msg";
          msg.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Please enter a valid age"));

          messageInserted = true;
          target.parentElement.appendChild(msg);
        }
        target.focus();
        target.select();
      } else if (messageInserted === true){
        //When you get here, msg is a NEW span that has not been inserted.  Thus,
        //  you do not remove the span that has never been inserted.
        //document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1].removeChild(msg); //problem
        //You need to get a reference to the span you have already inserted.
        var currentMessage = document.getElementById('msg');
        currentMessage.parentNode.removeChild(currentMessage);
        //The user may change age back to NaN and need the message re-inserted.
        messageInserted = false;
      }
    }

    myForm.btnCheckForm.addEventListener("click", btnCheckFormClick);
    myForm.txtAge.addEventListener("blur", txtAgeBlur);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys, all your answers helped. Now I understand it.

Comment: @Peter, I'm happy to help.  BTW: you really should not be creating the `<span>` each time `txtAgeBlur` is called. There is no reason to create the `<span>` when you are not going to insert it. When possible, you should avoid doing unnecessary work in an event handler. Thus, the `<span>` should only be created within the `if (!messageInserted) {` where you are going to append the `<span>` to the `target`. That way it is only created when you are actually going to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Just 1 more thing. `w3schools` website says "removeChild() returns the removed node as a Node object, or null if the node does not exist." Can you please give a code example of this method returning null?

Comment: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_removechild.asp) is wrong in this instance. The specification, [DOM Level 3 Core: removeChild](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1734834066) states the return value is the removed node, or an exception is raised. Another good resource is Mozilla Developer Network. It is a bit more technical, but usually provides good information.  In this case, MDN's page for [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).